# Pass the url from the marker into the controller

Tags: swift, url, mkmapview, marker

I'm doing the app for viewing IP cameras and want to add cameras to the map so you can click on the desired marker and go to see the desired camera. I have a map and PlayerViewController which reproduce a webcam.

Now each marker only transmits the first stream of the webcam. Help me. How to make different webcam worked?

**ViewController**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    var moscow: [(name: String, URLs:String, img:String, latitude: Double, longitude: Double)] =
    [("cam1", "http://example/1.m3u8", "1.jpg", 55.753989, 37.620235),
     ("cam2", "http://example/2.m3u8", "2.jpg", 55.741308, 37.653914),
     ("cam3","http://example/3.m3u8","3.jpg", 55.742468, 37.629292)]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var latitudes = moscow.map({ $0.latitude })
        var longitudes = moscow.map({ $0.longitude })
        var annotations = moscow.map({ $0.name })

        for i in 0...2 {
            let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitudes[i], longitudes[i])
            let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.003, 0.003)
            let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(coordinate, span)
            mapView.setRegion(region, animated:true)

            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = coordinate
            annotation.title = annotations[i]
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
        print(#function)
    }

    // Called when the annotation was added
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            return nil
        }

        let reuseId = "pin"
        var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
        if pinView == nil {
            pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
            pinView?.animatesDrop = true
            pinView?.canShowCallout = true
            pinView?.isDraggable = true
            pinView?.pinColor = .purple

            let rightButton: AnyObject! = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.detailDisclosure)
            pinView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton as? UIView
        } else {
            pinView?.annotation = annotation
        }

        return pinView
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
        print(#function)

        if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "toTheMoon", sender: self)
        }
    }

    override  func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "toTheMoon" {
            let controller = segue.destination as! PlayerViewController

            var urlll = moscow.map({ $0.URLs })

            for i in 0...2 {
                controller.webcamURL = urlll[i] // only first cam play
            }
        }
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, didChange newState: MKAnnotationViewDragState, fromOldState oldState: MKAnnotationViewDragState) {
        if newState == MKAnnotationViewDragState.ending {
            let droppedAt = view.annotation?.coordinate
            print(droppedAt)
        } 
    }
}
```

**PlayerViewController**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class PlayerViewController: AVPlayerViewController {

    var webcamURL:  String!
    var webcamTitle: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = webcamTitle
        let url = URL(string: webcamURL)
        player = AVPlayer(url: url!)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        player!.play()     
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        self.player!.pause()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        player = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me if my answer help you? please give me feedback if it does accept my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of All `MKAnnotation` is a Protocol so you can implement this protocol in your model class, lets say "Camera"

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class Camera: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

    var name: String = ""
    var urlString :String = ""
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)
    var imageName : String = ""

    init(name:String,camUrl:String,imageNamed:String,latitude:CLLocationDegrees,longitude:CLLocationDegrees) {
        super.init()
        self.name = name
        self.urlString = camUrl
        self.imageName = imageNamed

        guard latitude != 0 && longitude != 0 else
        {
            return
        }

        guard latitude.isNaN || longitude.isNaN else
        {
            return
        }

        self.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    }

    // Title and subtitle for use by selection UI.
    public var title: String? {
        get{
            return self.name
        }
    }

}
```

Then you can reduce your ViewController code like this

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    var moscow: [Camera] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.moscow = [Camera(name: "cam1", camUrl: "http://example/1.m3u8", imageNamed: "1.jpg", latitude: 55.753989, longitude: 37.620235),
                       Camera(name: "cam2", camUrl: "http://example/2.m3u8", imageNamed: "2.jpg", latitude: 55.741308, longitude: 37.653914),
                       Camera(name: "cam3", camUrl: "http://example/3.m3u8", imageNamed: "3.jpg", latitude: 55.742468, longitude: 37.629292)]

        self.mapView.addAnnotations(self.moscow)
        self.mapView.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}

extension ViewController : MKMapViewDelegate
{
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
        print(#function)
    }

    // Called when the annotation was added
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            return nil
        }

        let reuseId = "pin"
        var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
        if pinView == nil {
            pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
            pinView?.animatesDrop = true
            pinView?.canShowCallout = true
            pinView?.isDraggable = true
            pinView?.pinColor = .purple

            let rightButton: AnyObject! = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.detailDisclosure)
            pinView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton as? UIView
        } else {
            pinView?.annotation = annotation
        }

        return pinView
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
        print(#function)

        let camera = view.annotation as! Camera
        if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "toTheMoon", sender: camera)
        }
    }

    override  func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "toTheMoon" {
            let controller = segue.destination as! PlayerViewController

            controller.webcamURL = (sender as! Camera).urlString
            controller.webcamTitle = (sender as! Camera).name
        }
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, didChange newState: MKAnnotationViewDragState, fromOldState oldState: MKAnnotationViewDragState) {
        if newState == MKAnnotationViewDragState.ending {
            let droppedAt = view.annotation?.coordinate
            print(droppedAt)
        } 
    }

}
```

Hope this helps